# .NET MVC - How to create HtmlHelperExtension in VB instead of C#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, html-helper

i need to create a HtmlHelperExtension in VB instead of C#. I cannot find any example showing how it's done. Since static classes don't exist in VB (modules are used instead), I'm not really sure on how to create a HtmlHelperExtension...

This is what I figured out, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
Public Module HtmlHelperExtensions
    Public Function PartnumberLink(ByVal HtmlHelper As HtmlHelper, ByVal LinkText As String, ByVal Partnumber As String) As String
        Return "<a href=""/part/" & Partnumber & """>" & LinkText & "</a>"
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx):

```
Public Module HtmlHelperExtensions
    <Extension()>_
    Public Function PartnumberLink(ByVal HtmlHelper As HtmlHelper, ByVal LinkText As String, ByVal Partnumber As String) As String
        Return "<a href=""/part/" & Partnumber & """>" & LinkText & "</a>"
    End Function
End Module
```